# Quotation mark completion with f-strings in Sublime Text's Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, sublimetext3

When I type a quotation mark in Sublime Text 3 (3176) it auto completes with a closing quotation mark.

e.g. I type `"` I get `"<cursor>"`

This is great and I now expect it all the time. However with the introduction of f-strings into Python if I type `f"` I get `f"<cursor>` rather than `f"<cursor>"`. This is not a large problem by any means but it's not as fluid as I feel it could be.

I think the autocompletion rules doesn't add an extra quotation mark if there is a character to the left of the cursor as that's generally when you're trying to input a closing quotation mark.

Is there a way to modify the rules so that it will input the closing quotation mark if the character to the left is an "f"? To avoid a weird use case when you are genuinely trying to end a string finishing with an "f" perhaps there could be an `and` condition to check for an opening bracket, white space, or equality sign to the left of the "f" for the high-use cases of `print(f"string"`, `foo = f"string"`, and `foo =f"string"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Simply add the following to your User keymap file (Preferences menu -> Key Bindings. The User keymap is the one on the right hand side):

```js
// Auto-pair quotes even after string modifiers.
// Copied over from the default bindings with modifications to `preceding_text`
// and an added selector condition.
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\"$0\""}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "(?i)\\b[bfru]+$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python" },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["'"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "'$0'"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "(?i)\\b[bfru]+$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python" },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.single - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

[This will be shipped by default in a future build of ST.](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/1502)

It uses a scope selector to determine whether the caret is already inside a string or not, so the case of finishing a string with an `f` character isn't a problem.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Worked exactly as expected.